# Check Continuos Connection not launching in BaseActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, observable, rx-java2

I'm using the next library [**ReactiveNetwork**](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork/tree/RxJava2.x) to listen the changes on the network to detect when the network is disconnected, but I've implemented this on the BaseActivity but is not doing nothing.

Have I something wrong? Let me know.

```
  public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      private Disposable networkDisposable;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        connectivityMonitorized();
        safelyDispose(networkDisposable);
      }

      private void safelyDispose(Disposable... disposables) {
        for (Disposable subscription : disposables) {
          if (subscription != null && !subscription.isDisposed()) {
              subscription.dispose();
          }
        }
      }

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    public void connectivityMonitorized(){

        networkDisposable = ReactiveNetwork
                .observeNetworkConnectivity(this)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(connectivity -> {
                    if (connectivity.state() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED || connectivity.state() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTING) {
                        //TODO DIALOG SHOWING DISCONNECTED
                    }
                });

        }

}
```

I'm using this BaseActivity to extends in other activities.

Thanks

Comment: *Have I something wrong?* yeah where are you calling the function

Comment: safelyDispose(networkDisposable);

Answer (score 0):

You are disposing the networkDisposable as soon as subscribed ideally it should be disposed on the activity destroy that's why you are not getting any network updates move the safelyDispose() to on destroy

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   safelyDispose(networkDisposable);
}
```